# Python: How to mock HTTPSConnection request and response object using json.load

Tags: python-3.x, httpresponse, httpconnection

I need to mock below method in my unit test.

```
def get_app_info(role):
  conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(url)
  conn.request(
      method="GET",
      url="/v1/profile",
      headers={
          "appName": app["name"],
          "appRole": role
      }
  )

  response = conn.getresponse()
  res_data = json.load(response)
  conn.close()

  return res_data
```

I tried to patch `@patch('http.client.HTTPSConnection')`, so request is mocking but its failing at `json.load` with below error.

> raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
>   TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not
>   MagicMock

I tried mocking as below

```
def mocked_response(*args, **kwargs):
class MockResponse:
    def __init__(self, json_data, status_code):
        self.json_data = json_data
        self.status_code = status_code

    def json(self):
        return self.json_data

return MockResponse(
    {
            "url": "/test/home
        },
        200)
```

class MyGreatClassTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

```
@patch('http.client.HTTPSConnection')
@patch('http.client.HTTPResponse')
def test_retrive_token(self, mock_con, mock_resp,  side_effect = mocked_response):

    json_data = common.retrieve_access_token("sometoken")
    print(json_data)
```

Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `context=json.dump(response)` first then try `json.load(context)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to run my unit test cases while mocking HTTPSConnection and HTTPResponse. @patch won't work in this scenario as every time http.client.HTTPSConnection(url) will create new Mock object. So created Mock Request, response and message classes.

New Mock classes created as

```
from MockHTTPResponse import mock_response
```

def mock_http_connon(self):

```
class MockHTTPSConnection(object):
    print(object)
    def request(method, url, body, headers):
        print('request is executed')

    def headers(self):
        return "content-type", "accept"

    def getresponse():
        return mock_response()

    def close():
        print("close MockHTTPSConnection")

return MockHTTPSConnection
```

Similarly MockResponse and MockMessage.